# $PATH in a shell made by xterm not including a command location, but shell still able to execute it

Tags: debian, path, xterm, fluxbox

I am setting up a Debian 10 with fluxbox window manager. One of the components I need is miniconda, I've installed everything from the initial bash (no desktop) and everything works fine. Miniconda installation alters the /.bashrc file, appending the following lines to its contents:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

It works fine, the initial (no wm) bash do properly set $PATH, could run conda without problems and `echo $PATH` would display the included conda installation directory accordingly after a fresh login.

For a terminal created using xterm under Fluxbox, however, I found a behaviour which I would describe as bizarre:

1) Trying to find 'conda' using `which` gives no answer;

2) `echo $PATH` does not display the conda installation directory;

3) Yet, `conda` *still works*, as I can do `conda update conda` without problems;

4) After that, the conda installation directory is still not prepended to $PATH and `which` is still not able to find it;

5) Asking for conda environment activation, e.g. `conda activate base` works fine, and doing so makes the shell update $PATH properly.

I just want to know why it happens. There is something in this process I could not understand well:
How exactly is the way the environment variables are passed to the shell created by xterm in this case?
Why is it able to run `conda`, even though `which` could not find it in $PATH?

===EDIT===
Including the outputs as required:

```
root@Zumbi:~# type conda > type_conda_out.txt

conda is a function
conda () 
{ 
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA;
    else
        \local cmd="$1";
        shift;
        case "$cmd" in 
            activate | deactivate)
                __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@"
            ;;
            install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall)
                CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}";
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path;
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@";
                \local t1=$?;
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}";
                if [ $t1 = 0 ]; then
                    __conda_reactivate;
                else
                    return $t1;
                fi
            ;;
            *)
                CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}";
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path;
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@";
                \local t1=$?;
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}";
                return $t1
            ;;
        esac;
    fi
}

root@Zumbi:~# /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook > hook_out.txt

export CONDA_EXE='/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda'
export _CE_M=''
export _CE_CONDA=''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE='/opt/miniconda3/bin/python'

# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause

__add_sys_prefix_to_path() {
    # In dev-mode CONDA_EXE is python.exe and on Windows
    # it is in a different relative location to condabin.
    if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${CONDA_EXE}")
    else
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${CONDA_EXE}")
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${SYSP}")
    fi

    if [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        PATH="${SYSP}/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Scripts:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/usr/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/mingw-w64/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}:${PATH}"
    else
        PATH="${SYSP}/bin:${PATH}"
    fi
    \export PATH
}

__conda_hashr() {
    if [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
        \rehash
    elif [ -n "${POSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
        :  # pass
    else
        \hash -r
    fi
}

__conda_activate() {
    if [ -n "${CONDA_PS1_BACKUP:+x}" ]; then
        # Handle transition from shell activated with conda <= 4.3 to a subsequent activation
        # after conda updated to >= 4.4. See issue #6173.
        PS1="$CONDA_PS1_BACKUP"
        \unset CONDA_PS1_BACKUP
    fi

    \local cmd="$1"
    shift
    \local ask_conda
    CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}"
    __add_sys_prefix_to_path
    ask_conda="$(PS1="$PS1" "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA shell.posix "$cmd" "$@")" || \return $?
    rc=$?
    PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}"
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    if [ $rc != 0 ]; then
        \export PATH
    fi
    __conda_hashr
}

__conda_reactivate() {
    \local ask_conda
    CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}"
    __add_sys_prefix_to_path
    ask_conda="$(PS1="$PS1" "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA shell.posix reactivate)" || \return $?
    PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}"
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    __conda_hashr
}

conda() {
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA
    else
        \local cmd="$1"
        shift
        case "$cmd" in
            activate|deactivate)
                __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@"
                ;;
            install|update|upgrade|remove|uninstall)
                CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}"
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}"
                if [ $t1 = 0 ]; then
                    __conda_reactivate
                else
                    return $t1
                fi
                ;;
            *)
                CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}"
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}"
                return $t1
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}

if [ -z "${CONDA_SHLVL+x}" ]; then
    \export CONDA_SHLVL=0
    # In dev-mode CONDA_EXE is python.exe and on Windows
    # it is in a different relative location to condabin.
    if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA+x}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        PATH="$(\dirname "$CONDA_EXE")/condabin${PATH:+":${PATH}"}"
    else
        PATH="$(\dirname "$(\dirname "$CONDA_EXE")")/condabin${PATH:+":${PATH}"}"
    fi
    \export PATH

    # We're not allowing PS1 to be unbound. It must at least be set.
    # However, we're not exporting it, which can cause problems when starting a second shell
    # via a first shell (i.e. starting zsh from bash).
    if [ -z "${PS1+x}" ]; then
        PS1=
    fi
fi
root@Zumbi:~# type -f conda
bash: type: conda: not found
```

===EDIT 2===
Only now, while editing FB's menu, I could see how xterm is called: it is done by a wrapper:
`x-terminal-emulator -T "Bash" -e /bin/bash --login`
and the `--login` option, as explained in [bash documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash),

> Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell

So it explains why bash was not getting $PATH.
Using `fbrun xterm` results in a bash with the default, initialized system $PATH as expected.

Comment: It is the same user in both cases? The answer may be in the output of `/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook`. Maybe it defines an alias or sets the binary path via `hash`. What is the output of `type conda`?

Comment: Same user, root; Sorry, didn't understand quite well which outuput or how to check what you are referering about in `/opt/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook`; `type conda` returns: `conda is a function`, and includes the code right after.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the output of `type -f conda`?

Comment: Phrasing this in terms of "xterm executes" and "terminal executes" is wrong.  It is not XTerm that is executing stuff here.  A terminal is not a shell.

Comment: @AndyDalton outuputs included as asked.

Comment: @JdeBP Agreed. Do you recommend editing the question for better reading?

Comment: I do, yes.  Conflating the twain is not a premise of the question so correcting this doesn't change the substance of the question.  I also recommend that after reading the output of `type` and https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980 that you answer yourself.  (-:

Comment: Thanks, @JdeBP. I will read that conda issue and try to understand it enough to write an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Running the command `conda` works because it is defined as a shell function during shell initialization. The function contains the full path of the binary so there is no need for looking it up in `$PATH`.

`which` does not show shell functions (by default).